# When a PC deep one hybrid undergoes the final change, does the GM control it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

Due to the extraordinary ability final change, a [deep one hybrid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/race-points-unknown/deep-one-hybrid/) turns into an actual [deep one](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/deep-one/) a few months after reaching venerable age. The text says nothing about this *real* deep one then becoming a monster under the DM's control. Does a player whose PC deep one hybrid becomes a real deep one see the GM take control of his character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

The transformation functions identically to *reincarnate*, so the creature remains a PC, and their body's age is now young adult.

> This transformation functions as the reincarnate spell

(from the description of the deep one hybrid race)

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't prevent a GM from saying you cannot play a Deep One PC or Deep One Hybrid that might *final change* during the campaign.